# Django: custom constructor for form class, trouble with accessing data from request.POST

Tags: python, django, post, webforms

I have written custom constructor for a form, the whole form class looks like this:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(label = "Plik")

    def __init__(self, coto, naglowek, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.coto = coto
        self.naglowek = naglowek
```

When submitting form, in my view, I have something like

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        add_form(request.FILES['file'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('uploaded/')
```

The problem is, that when I am creating form in this way in my view, I am not passing **coto** and **naglowek**, so when I am calling **form.is_valid()** --> it returns false.

The template which passess it looks like:

```
<table class="uploadform">
<form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% for form in forms %} 
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.naglowek }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.file }}</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="{{ form.coto }}" id="{{ form.coto }}" value="Wyślij"></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</form>
</table>
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

**[EDIT]**
I might not say this clearlly enough, but I will try my best:

When I am submitting this form, in view, I need to know which submit button was pressed - I have many of them assigned to single form. From what I know, when I am assigning id to submit button, it should be availible in post, right? The trick is, that it is not availible.

I have two questions:
 * What needs to be done, If I want to know which submit button was pressed? Is assigning the name the only way?
 * Is there any error in my logic?

Comment: Please put your actual error messages and traceback in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a mess.  There's code and there's an edit with another question.  The edit question has nothing to do with the title.

Please update this question to be your *real* question.

If you have multiple submit buttons, you must give them distinct names or values (or both).  Here's our code which uses distinct values to distinguish which button was clicked.

```
        <form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="{{e.id}}"/>
            {% ifequal object.workflow "uploaded" %}
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Validate"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% ifequal object.workflow "validated" %}
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Load"/>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% ifequal object.workflow "processed" %}
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Undo"/>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% ifequal object.workflow "failed" %}
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Validate"/>
            {% endifequal %}
        </form>
```

The view function has this kind of thing:

```
            if request.POST['action'] == "Delete":
```

to change the action based on the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.POST['coto']
request.POST['naglowek']
```

I guess.

Comment: I tried - and it's not working. I might messed this one somewhere, but I dunno where. Thank You for trying to help.

Comment: may be you could check your html to see what is actually being submitted?

Comment: By "it's not working" I mean, that I get error "Key 'coto' not found in <QueryDict: {u'slownik': [u'Wyślij']}>"

Answer (score 0):

You've redefined default form constructor and change its parameters order. So you have to instantiate your custom form with explicit naming of arguments:

```
form = UploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, coto=..., naglowek=...)
```

Comment: Alex, I know that I redefined parameters order - the trick here is that I cannot access 'coto' and 'naglowek' in POST dictionary.